# I want to use AJAX to dynamically generate layout based on the ID of a link clicked

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am attempting to use AJAX to generate PHP to be displayed inside of a div based on the ID of the link clicked.   (I haven't dealt with HTML formatting yet, just want to figure this out first)

My Code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $(".myClass h3").click(function(){  

            var clickID = $(this).attr('id'); //For sake of argument lets say id = 1.

            $.ajax({                                                          
                  url: 'landingPage.php',                  
                  data: {ProductIDNumber: clickID}, 
                          success: function(html) {
                      $('#container').append(html); 
                  }
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have dealt with getting the PHP to run when the url is landingPage.php?ProductIDNumber=1 and that all works properly, I just don't quite grasp how to return the resultant HTML.

Edits made and commented on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include `success`, which is run once the response is received, similar to;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() 
{
    $(".myClass h3").click(function(){  

        var clickID = $(this).attr('id'); //For sake of argument lets say id = 1.

        $.ajax({                                                          
            url: 'landingPage.php',
            data: {
                ProductIDNumber : clickID
            },
            success: function(html) {
                 // Do what you need to here with 'html'
                 $('#container').append(html);   
            }                 
        });
});
</script>
```

As Alvaro said the structure of the `data` was also incorrect

[Here's a link](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to the jQuery docs where you can find out more about the parameters and options you have (such as handling fails etc)

Comment: Looks right to me yeah, for readability's sake it'd be better to align your code neater but functionally that doesn't matter

Comment: Thanks! I had all of the content loading on Document Ready with PHP, (in order to keep as hard-coding to a minimum and make maintenance significantly easier) but it was alot of stress right at document load, a lot of images and menus to load all at once, so I'm trying to break each "step" in the menu navigation down into click events with AJAX calls to spread out the load time. Once I get the PHP tweaked i'll let you know how it worked!

Comment: How much of the page is dynamically generated? Ideally it's the amount of code being pulled in via AJAX you'd want to keep to a minimum to prevent slow loading

Comment: If you exclude my scripts, the whole document is only about 18 lines of code. Since I want the webpage to require minimum maintenance I am generating all of the content dynamically from a database with PHP, formatting it, and then including it into the "home page" (Site.php). landingPage.php controls the content of a particular DIV  (the name is horrible but if I change it when I try to explain to the sales people they get confused). And the content put into this DIV is driven by a set of menus that the user navigates through. MainCat->SubCat->myClass h3, and the resulting info is displayed.

Comment: The AJAX works, I'm getting the content that I need! (now it's time to step my way backwards and start AJAX-ing my PHP instead of having lists of divs contained in wrapper classes).

Comment: Could this content not be dynamically created as the page loads rather than via AJAX? Anyway, glad the jQuery is working :)

Comment: By using AJAX in response to click events, I can take wrapper classes that have 10-12 identical divs inside of them (with different product content) and instead use only the wrapper class and "flag" it with the product ID that I want to grab. Currently it all loads on form load, and that ends up giving us slightly over 100 divs contained in wrapper classes, and causes the Site to load incredibly slow over phones, by doing this we reduce how bulky the loading need to be.

Answer (score 1):

the data is wrong,

it is like this:

```
data: {varname: value, varname1: value},
```

Comment: So in my example it would be:    "data: {ProductIDNumber: clickID}, "?

Comment: change `data: {"ProductIDNumber=": clickID},` to `data: {ProductIDNumber: clickID},`